# ASP.NET web forms- how to avoid duplication between client and server side validations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, webforms

I red many posts here on stackoverflow and searched online but still haven't found a solution that works for me.

I have 2 applications - the first is using web forms and the other uses MVC.
I know that MVC supports data annotations on model fields so it spares me from maintaining validations also on client side.

I need something similar that will work also in web forms, I want to create data annotations (or any other thing that will work) that will serve both of my applications, without having to maintain duplicate validations on server & client side.

Is such thing even possible?

Answer (score 4):

> without having to maintain duplicate validations on server & client side.

On the contrary, you will want duplicate validation: both client-side and server-side validation.

- You'll want client-side validation for the sake of user-experience: so users get immediate feedback of invalid input without needing to POST the form (and wait for the response) and the jarring experience of a page refresh.
- You'll want server-side validation because you **should never trust the client**.

The good news is that if you use ASP.NET's built-in validation features correctly then you don't need to go through a lot of effort to get both server-side and client-side data validation.

In ASP.NET WebForms this is done with the "validation controls" like `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` - it provides both server-side and client-side validation. Client-side validation is enabled by setting `EnableClientScript="True"` which will automatically inject the necessary Javascript into your page. Many web-developers (myself included) dislike this "feature" of ASP.NET WebForms because it necessarily means you lose control over the rendered page.

In ASP.NET MVC there is also automatic server+client-side validation but it's more involved: you need to add your own reference to jQuery's Validation library and enable it in web.config. See this article for details: https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/03/23/manually-use-mvc-client-side-validation/

(BTW, please note the difference between input data validation and input data verification: validation is checking that input data conforms with required/optional checks, matches certain formats (e.g. dates, currency) and other "static" rules and do not require database lookups, for example - whereas *verification* involves comparing input data with known data to verify and enforce authorization rules, existence checks, and so on - which are more expensive to carry-out, such as checking with a database or third-party webservice).

Answer (score 0):

Well .net web forms has  Validation tools way before, which can be found under Toolbox
       as per using data annotation  am not 100% weither you can use it what i would do is adding the required  references into the project and try with it. note that the dataannotation bind the inputs by the name and not by the id of the input so try puuting same name to the client side inputs too

other way around is data annotation uses jquery validator plugin which you can use in web forms manually